# Did arena reward pack types change with the release of The Grand Tournament?

Tags: hearthstone

Following The Grand Tournament's release, does the arena now reward Grand Tournament packs in lieu of the previously rewarded Goblins & Gnomes packs?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i do not have the gold currently, but wanted to know so i can plan to buy a pack or go into the arena

Comment: It's actually not very easy to check for yourself; the system now awards a random pack, so there's a 1/3 chance (actually lower, see Mad Scientist's answer) to get a G&G pack which would at first suggest that nothing's changed, and a 1/3 chance to get a TGT pack which would suggest that the old system is in place (always get a pack from the latest expansion,) and a 1/3 chance to get a basic pack which would just be confusing. You'd need several arena runs to independently deduce what the actual change is.

Comment: @moyli To be fair, it is easy to check for yourself due to the fact that it has been officially announced a number of times.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Arena now rewards a random card pack.

[Directly from Blizzard:](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19843158/the-grand-tournament%E2%84%A2-now-available-8-24-2015)

> **Arena Rewards**
>
> Players will now have a chance to receive any of the current
>   Hearthstone card packs (which include the Classic Hearthstone set,
>   Goblins vs Gnomes, and The Grand Tournament) whenever a card pack is
>   awarded, with a greater chance to receive The Grand Tournament card
>   packs.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise they had changed the system for rewards. Must have missed that message